# "mexFunction is missing" Error while obtaining sizes from MEX S-Function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, mex, s-function

First of all thanks a lot for reading this post and being able to help.
I have an .cpp custom code and I could create a mexa64 typing:

```
mex mycpp.cpp
```

Now I would like to implement this .mexa64 file into Simulink. I have create a mycpp.c and mycpp_wrapper.c with simulink functions and inputs/outputs (as if I was using s-function builder).
So Now I open Simulink with S.Function and I type mycpp on it but it gives me this error:

```
Error while obtaining sizes from MEX S-function 'universaltest' in 'uni_simulink/S-Function'.
Caused by:
Invalid MEX-file '/home/user/Workspace/universaltest.mexa64': Function mexFunction is missing.
```

how can I solve it?
By the way, I can not use S-Function builder because it is using gcc compiler and not g++... I try to solve it with "mex -setup C++" but it still does not work. Does anyone know how I can solve this as well?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Rather than an `int main` function, you'll need to write a `mexFunction` which serves as an [entry point](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexfunction.html).